# How to check if current user has filled out a document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections, one is users and the other is invoice details. On user login, I need to check that the current user has filled out all fields in the invoice details collection. So need to show an alert as soon as user logs in to say to fill out details.

Both collections have the same UID's

```
checkJob = () => {

  firebase.firestore().collection('invoice_details').where("accountname", "==", "").get().then((resultSnapShot) => {


          if (resultSnapShot.size == 0) {

              Alert.alert("Details need to be updated")

          } else {

              Alert.alert("Details ok")
          }

      })

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your invoice document generate after user submit some data then you can check if document exists of that user.

```
var docRef = db.collection("invoice_details").doc(userId);

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: @Ding0 yes if invoice_details collection does not contains user key document then just set alert on it